# Reading GCS Files from Pcollection of file paths cannot scale to multiple workers in dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a dataflow file written in Apache Beam which read millions of gcs objects containing logs from gcs folder containing file pointer files of these millions of objects. This pipeline cannot scale to more workers. It is stuck in one worker.

Pipeline code:

```
Pcollection<String> bucket = Create.of("gs://file-pointer-bucket/*") --> This bucket has five files each containing 500K file paths.

Pcollection<String> filePaths = bucket.apply(FileIO.matchAll())
                .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
                .apply(TextIO.readFiles())

PCollection<String> validFilePaths = filePaths.apply(Filter.by("find valid paths")) --> This will filter file paths to little less based on time range.

PCollection<String> logs = validFilePaths.apply(FileIO.matchAll())
                .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
                .apply(TextIO.readFiles())
```

Why dataflow cannot scale to a very high number of workers to read these 500k files vs getting stuck at one worker and reading each file seriously?

I tried putting Shuffle at different stage and see if breaking fusion can solve this but no success.

Comment: Assuming you use autoscaling, here is how Dataflow scales up for a batch job: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/horizontal-autoscaling#batch. Does your job load trigger autoscaling?

Comment: @XQHu Whta do you mean by load trigger autoscaling? validFilePaths will few million paths pointing to gz objects. I think the issue can be one of the following:

1.  `Dataflow automatically chooses the number of workers based on the estimated total amount of work in each stage of your pipeline, which is dependent on both the input size and the current throughput.` In my case, it is not able to figure out the total amount of work due to input is few millions gz files.
2. I don't think parallelism is limited due to unparallelizable work asI have few millions paths as input to last transform.

Comment: I mean scaling up or down is determined by some metrics. For example, when average worker CPU usage is lower than 5%, no scaling occurs.

Comment: What parameters do you pass when you submit the job?

Comment: Found the issue. Doing `MatchAll` for millions of file paths is the problem. Added shuffle between `MatchAll` and `readMatches.readfiles` and it showed MatchAll fusion with read was making it single threaded. Is there any way to read Pcollcection of FilePaths without MatchAll?